# Problem navigating between screens; I need to have a stack with a specific order

Tags: flutter

I need to create a precise layout of pages: first page, email registration, data registration, telephone number registration. Even if the app opens on the phone registration page, I want the previous ones to always be in the stack.

This happens because if I start the registration process and close the app before finishing it, I want the last screen displayed to open directly when the app is restarted, without restarting the process from 0.
I've tried running more Navigator.push afterwards but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Is a stack really necessary?

Maybe you can open the last page used, and use `Navigator.pushAndReplace` to move back and forth between pages.

Otherwise, better state your initial problem, as this question seems to be a case of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Consider the registration process consisting of the following pages: home page, email registration, data registration, and telephone number registration. If, at a certain point in the registration (for example I have only completed the email registration), and the program is closed, when the application is restarted the data registration page will be shown directly. In this way, if from the data registration page I want to return to the email registration page, I cannot, because it has never been loaded.